# Using adamic_adar_index in Python's Networkx

Tags: python, generator, networkx

I'm trying to use the function "adamic_adar_index" in Python's networkx package.  I'm following this example in the NetworkX documentation: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.link_prediction.adamic_adar_index.html

```
import networkx as nx 
G = nx.complete_graph(5) 
preds = nx.adamic_adar_index(G, [(0, 1), (2, 3)]) 
for u, v, p in preds:
     '(%d, %d) -> %.8f' % (u, v, p)
```

The function returns a generator object named "preds", but for some reason, when I convert it to a list using list(preds), it returns an empty list.  I'm trying to get a list of 3-tuples with each tuple in the form (u,v,p), but having some trouble actually getting it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a print statement to your last line:

```
for u, v, p in preds:
    print '(%d, %d) -> %.8f' % (u, v, p)
```